I can't fetch the JWT token from the backend to the frontend
Could someone help me understand the issue? Everything works fine on the backend. The problem lies specifically on the frontend. The user registers on the page at http://localhost:8080/host_page, and the data is handled by the RegisterController. If registration is successful, the user is redirected to the page http://localhost:8080/personal_office. The issue is with managing the JWT token on the frontend. When I turn off security checks, all pages in the browser open. What and where should I add to make the frontend retrieve the JWT token from the backend, store it in the browser's local storage, and prevent the user from receiving a 403 error?This is my first experience in passing the JWT token from the backend to the frontend. I couldn't find suitable articles online about my situation. Here is my controller.
    @RestController
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
   @RequestMapping("/register")
     public class RegisterController {
      private final UserService userService;
     private final DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService;
     private final JWTService jwtService;
     private final PaymentController paymentController;
      private final SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;

     @PostMapping
     public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody UserRegistrationDTO request) {
     try {
        if (userService.isPhoneNumberRegistered(request.getPhoneNumber())) {
            log.error("User with phone number {} already exists", request.getPhoneNumber());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("User with phone number "                  + request.getPhoneNumber() + " already exists");
        }
        if (userService.isEmailRegistered(request.getEmail())) {
            log.error("User with email {} already exists", request.getEmail());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("User with email " +   request.getEmail() + " already exists");
        }

        BigDecimal bonusPrice =  subscriptionRepository.findBySubscriptionName("REGISTRATION").getSubscriptionPrice();
        TransactionDTO transactionDTO = TransactionDTO.builder()
                .outputCardNumber(request.getUserBankCard().getCardNumber())
                .sum(bonusPrice)
                .cardExpirationDate(request.getUserBankCard().getCardExpirationDate())
                .cvv(request.getUserBankCard().getCvv()).build();
        ResponseEntity<String> paymentResponse = paymentController.payment(transactionDTO);
        if (paymentResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            userService.registerUser(request);
            UserDetails userDetails =  databaseUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String.valueOf(request.getPhoneNumber()));
            String jwtToken = jwtService.generateJwtToken(userDetails);
            log.info("User with phone number {} registered successfully ",  request.getPhoneNumber());
            log.info("Generated JWT token: {}", jwtToken);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new RedirectResponseDTO("/personal_office", jwtToken));
        } else if (paymentResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
            String errorMessage = paymentResponse.getBody();
            log.warn("Payment failed: {}", errorMessage);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(errorMessage);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Payment failed");
        }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An error occurred while updating subscription", e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An unexpected  error occurred");
        }
          }
          }

my WebSecurityConfig
      @Configuration
      @RequiredArgsConstructor
         @EnableWebSecurity
      public class WebSecurityConfig {
      private final JWTTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig;

      @Bean
       public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/host_page", "/register", "/login" ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/*", "/v3/api-docs/**",    "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/personal_office/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/main").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/free_subscription").hasAnyRole("FREE", "OPTIMAL", "MAXIMUM",  "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/optimal_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "OPTIMAL",  "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/maximum_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore((Filter) jwtTokenConfig,   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            return http.build();
           }
           }

and my HTML files
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Host Page</title>
      <style>
        body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
      .welcome {
         text-align: center;
      }
      .form-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
       }
      form {
        width: 45%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        }
       h2 {
        text-align: center;
        }
        label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: center;
          }
           input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
         }
           input[type="submit"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
         }
          input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
         }
      .error {
        color: red;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
       }
       .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
       }
      .form-group label {
        display: block;
       }
      .form-group input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
       .form-group .half-width {
        width: calc(50% - 5px);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
       }
       .form-group .half-width label {
        display: block;
      }
       .form-group .half-width input[type="text"] {
        width: calc(100% - 10px);
        margin-bottom: 0;
        }
         </style>
          <script>
              function submitRegistrationForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('regPhoneNumber').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('regEmail').value;
        var bankCardNumber = document.getElementById('regBankCardNumber').value;
        var cardExpirationDate = document.getElementById('cardExpirationDate').value;
        var cvv = document.getElementById('cvv').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('regPassword').value;

        var userData = {
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            email: email,
            userBankCard: {
                cardNumber: bankCardNumber,
                cardExpirationDate: cardExpirationDate,
                cvv: cvv
            },
            password: password
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userData)
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return response.text().then(text => { throw new Error(text) });
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', data.jwtToken);
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/personal_office';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
         });
          }
        </script>
        </head>
         <body>
            <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to Host Page</h1>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form id="registrationForm" onsubmit="submitRegistrationForm(event)" method="post">
           <h2>Registration Form</h2>
           <div class="form-group">
        <label for="regPhoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="regPhoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
        <label for="regEmail">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="regEmail" name="email" required>
           </div>
             <div class="form-group">
        <label for="regBankCardNumber">Bank Card Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="regBankCardNumber" name="bankCardNumber" required>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
        <div class="half-width">
            <label for="cardExpirationDate">Card Expiration Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cardExpirationDate" name="cardExpirationDate" required>
        </div>
        <div class="half-width">
            <label for="cvv">CVV:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cvv" name="cvv" required>
        </div>
           </div>
          <div class="form-group">
        <label for="regPassword">Password:</label>
         <input type="password" id="regPassword" name="password" required>
           </div>
         <div class="error" id="registrationErrorMessages" style="display: none;"></div>
           <input type="submit" value="Register">
         </form>

     <form id="loginForm" onsubmit="submitLoginForm(event)" method="post">
      <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="loginPhoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="loginPhoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <label for="loginPassword">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="password" required>
         </div>
        <div class="error" id="loginErrorMessages" style="display: none;"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
           </form>
           </div>
         </body>
          </html>


     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>User Dashboard</title>
      <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

       header {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        }

        nav {
         background-color: #f4f4f4;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        }

         nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 5px;
         }

       section {
        padding: 20px;
         }
          </style>
          </head>
          <body>
         <header>
           <h1>Welcome to User Dashboard</h1>
           </header>
          <nav>
            <a href="/user/personal_data">Personal Data</a>
           <a href="/user/my_subscriptions">My Subscriptions</a>
           <a href="/user/all_subscriptions">All Subscriptions</a>
           </nav>
          <section>
             <div th:text="${content}"></div>
         </section>
             <script>
             const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                 const jwtToken = urlParams.get('jwtToken');

              if (jwtToken) {
             localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', jwtToken);
             } else {
           window.location.href = "/host_page";
            }
            </script>
          </body>
          </html>

Where are the errors? What needs to be done? Maybe someone will provide a link to the necessary article, or maybe someone will write the correct script and indicate where to put it.

For the subsequent request to http://localhost:8080/personal_office, you'll need to retrieve the token from localStorage and include it in the Authorization header of your fetch request.
.then(data => {
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', data.jwtToken);

    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/personal_office', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken // Include the jwtToken in the Authorization header
        }
    });
})


This should be in the file responsible for the page http://localhost:8080/personal_office? I added this script there. After navigating to the page http://localhost:8080/personal_office, I receive a 403 error, and in the DevTools headers, I don't see the token being pulled from the local storage. Although I see it on the page http://localhost:8080/host_page. What else could be the reason?





@PavelPavlik, have you tried to add jwtToken to request header in your js code ?

Here's my HTML file responsible for the page /personal_office. Is there an error here? Part 1: 




User Dashboard



Welcome to User Dashboard


Personal Data
My Subscriptions
All Subscriptions




Part 2:


looks correct to me. What is the current error information in the backend?

The question is still open, but the conditions have changed.  https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78664068
